# React skip API request if data already exists

Tags: reactjs

I have a scenario where I am making an API call in ComponentDidMount method.

I have declared a variable in constructor.

When the API call is successful I am storing the data in var that is declared in constructor.

Problem: I am unable to prevent the api call to be made if data is already there in the constructor variable.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.empData = [];
  }
  componentDidMount() {

      if(this.empData.length > 0){
        this.setState({employeeData: this.empData});
      } else {
        getEmpData(param1, options).then(
          employeeData => {
            this.setState({ employeeData });
            this.empData = employeeData;
          }
        );
      } 
  }
```

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: How is `empData` going to contain any value if its set to `this.empData = []`?

Comment: You store the received data in both the state (as the `employeeData` property) and in `this.empData`. Is this on purpose? Wouldn’t it suffice to store it just in the state?

Comment: Accessing state directly is not working before making an API call. Even if it works with state I am fine.

Answer (score 5):

That's because you are settig the state incorrectly.

Inside your constructor

`this.empData = [];` should be

```
this.state = { employeeData: []}
```

And when you are calling `setState` inside your promise that should be enough to set the state. No need to call `this.empData` explicitly.

And then

```
componentDidMount() {

      if(!this.state.employeeData.length){
        getEmpData(param1, options).then(
          employeeData => {
            this.setState({ employeeData });
          }
        );
      } 
  }
```

Comment: this is not working either. I have created a sample pen. If you see in the pen there is a networkcall always made .   https://codepen.io/phaniwithu/pen/XwbmjN

Comment: Here's a forked version - https://codepen.io/kushalmahajan/pen/VOLvrB?editors=1111. Just open up codepen console and let me know if it consoles more than once.